# python pandas plot with uneven timeseries index (with count evenly distributed)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

My dataframe has uneven time index.

how could I find a way to plot the data, and local the index automatically? I searched here, and I know I can plot something like

```
e.plot()
```

[image: even time]

but the time index (x axis) will be even interval, for example per 5 minutes.
if I have to 100 data in first 5 minutes and 6 data for the second 5 minutes, how do I plot 
with number of data evenly. and locate the right timestamp on x axis.

here's even count, but I don't know how to add time index.

```
plot(e['Bid'].values)
```

[image: even count]

example of data format as requested

Time,Bid

2014-03-05 21:56:05:924300,1.37275

2014-03-05 21:56:05:924351,1.37272

2014-03-05 21:56:06:421906,1.37275

2014-03-05 21:56:06:421950,1.37272

2014-03-05 21:56:06:920539,1.37275

2014-03-05 21:56:06:920580,1.37272

2014-03-05 21:56:09:071981,1.37275

2014-03-05 21:56:09:072019,1.37272

and here's the link
http://code.google.com/p/eu-ats/source/browse/trunk/data/new/eur-fix.csv

here's the code, I used to plot

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
e = pd.read_csv("data/ecb/eur.csv", dtype={'Time':object})
e.Time = pd.to_datetime(e.Time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
e.plot()

f = e.copy()
f.index = f.Time
x = [str(s)[:-7] for s in f.index]
ff = f.set_index(pd.Series(x))
ff.index.name = 'Time'
ff.plot()
```

**Update**:

I added two new plots for comparison to clarify the issue. Now I tried brute force to convert timestamp index back to string, and plot string as x axis. the format easily got messed up. it seems hard to customize location of x label.

[image: By ticks or data points]

[image: By time]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, it seems like what you're after is that you want to move around the x-tick locations so that there are an equal number of points between each tick.  And you'd like to have the grid drawn on these appropriately-located ticks.  Do I have that right?

If so:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbn

content = urllib.urlopen('https://eu-ats.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/data/new/eur-fix.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(content, header=0)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

every30 = df.loc[df.index % 30 == 0, 'Time'].values
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9, 5))
df.plot(x='Time', y='Bid', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks(every30)
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome, exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to reproduce your issue, but I can't seem to.  Can you have a look at this example and see how your situation differs?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbn

np.random.seed(0)

idx = pd.date_range('11:00', '21:30', freq='1min')
ser = pd.Series(data=np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx)
ser = ser.cumsum()

for i in range(20):
    for j in range(8):
        ser.iloc[10*i +j] = np.nan

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
ser.plot(ax=axes[0])
ser.dropna().plot(ax=axes[1])
```

gives the following two plots:

[image: two plots]

There are a couple differences between the graphs.  The one on the left doesn't connect the non-continuous bits of data.  And it lacks vertical gridlines.  But both seem to respect the actual index of the data.  Can you show an example of your `e` series?  What is the exact format of its index?  Is it a `datetime_index` or is it just text?

Edit:

Playing with this, my guess is that your index is actually just text.  If I continue from above with:

```
idx_str = [str(x) for x in idx]
newser = ser
newser.index = idx_str
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
newser.plot(ax=axes[0])
newser.dropna().plot(ax=axes[1])
```

then I get something like your problem:

[image: problem]

More edit:

If this is in fact your issue (the index is a bunch of strings, not really a bunch of timestamps) then you can convert them and all will be well:

```
idx_fixed = pd.to_datetime(idx_str)
fixedser = newser
fixedser.index = idx_fixed
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
fixedser.plot(ax=axes[0])
fixedser.dropna().plot(ax=axes[1])
```

produces output identical to the first code sample above.

Editing again:

To see the uneven spacing of the data, you can do this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
fixedser.plot(ax=axes[0], marker='.', linewidth=0)
fixedser.dropna().plot(ax=axes[1], marker='.', linewidth=0)
```

[image: fixed]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, in the exmaple you gave, you have evenly distributed timestamp. I will give a sample of the data, and let you know the difference. thanks, I tried to use a stupid way to plot string copy of axis, but the format is a mess. Thanks

Comment: Look more closely.  I start with an evenly spaced index.  Then I set a bunch of my data to `np.nan`.  Then I plot the data twice.  The first time I plot the data, I do it the natural way.  The second time, I `dropna()` it first, so the plotted series has uneven time steps at the beginning.  Look at the top right graph and you'll see how the line looks different on the left where the data is sparse.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try this one from scratch.  Does this solve your issue?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbn
import urllib

content = urllib.urlopen('https://eu-ats.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/data/new/eur-fix.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(content, header=0, index_col='Time')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
df.plot()
```

[image]

The thing is, you want to plot `bid` vs `time`. If you've put the times into your `index` then they become your x-axis for "free".  If the time data is just another column, then you need to specify that you want to plot `bid` as the y-axis variable and `time` as the x-axis variable.  So in your code above, even when you convert the `time` data to be `datetime` type, you were never instructing `pandas`/`matplotlib` to use those `datetimes` as the x-axis.

Comment: thank you for the reply. but I think you still didn't get my question, in the graph above, the time axis is evenly spaced(30second per grid), I don't want that, I want every grid to have the same number of y(Bid in this case), and locate some timestamp on the x axis, so the time won't be evenly spaced. Well it depends on the data, and my data surely is not time evenly distributed.

Comment: I add new plot which differs a lot to clarify the problem.