# Python Launcher closes before plotting (Mac OSX 10.10)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am struggling creating visual output with python. My system set-up is:

> MacBook Air (late 2010);
>   MacOSX 10.10.3 (14D136);
>   Python 2 and 3

Essentially I would like to plot uneven spaced data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258162/python-pandas-plot-with-uneven-timeseries-index-with-count-evenly-distributed/22261430#22261430) (sample code below).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbn

np.random.seed(0)

idx = pd.date_range('11:00', '21:30', freq='1min')
ser = pd.Series(data=np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx)
ser = ser.cumsum()

for i in range(20):
    for j in range(8):
        ser.iloc[10*i +j] = np.nan

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
ser.plot(ax=axes[0])
ser.dropna().plot(ax=axes[1])
```

When executing this code Python2 and Python3 will launch the *Python Launcher*. But before any output is produced the icon disappears from the dock. I run the code using

```
python2/3 plottest.py
```

Because I thought this might be a general problem with *matplotlib* I ran the following sample code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138026/seaborn-matplotlib-cannot-get-window-extent-w-o-renderer-runtimeerror)):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def plotClusterMap():
    a = pd.DataFrame(np.matrix('1 2; 3 4'))
    sns.clustermap(a)
    plt.show()
```

This code works in Python2&3.

The *Console* does not show any errors, also python does not show any errors. Could it simply be that the first code does not what I think it would do (namely displaying the graphs @8one6 shows in his answer)? And is there another way to display error/status messages?

Comment: running >nosetests seaborn< returns a lot of >RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer< and exits with >FAILED (SKIP=13, errors=15)<